# Bibliography order

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have some problems with the bibliography's ordering. I need the bibliography's elements to be ordered by author first and then by year. This is how some articles appear in my document now:

[image: Bibliography]

As you can see, they are ordered by author first and then by title. How can I modify the ordering? This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the option `sorting=nyt` when you load [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\usepackage[...,sorting=nyt,...]{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
```

This should tell `biber` to sort your bibliography by `n`ame first, then by `y`ear, then by `t`itle.

Alternatively, read the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), specifically section **4.5.5 Sorting** (p 160), where you can declare your own sorting scheme using `\DeclareSortingScheme`.